# How do I run WPF application from different directory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a basic tool using WPF.  If I run the tool from within the directory that it is located, everything works fine.  But, if I run from a different directory, nothing happens.  From the command line, it just returns to the prompt.  I haven't had this problem with WinForms applications and the directory does include the one dll the tool depends on.  What else could be going on?

EDIT:  I think I figured out this problem.  It was dying in InitializeComponent call within MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor.  A property being bound to was attempting to access an object that was null.  However, I have yet to figure out why the property is null only when I run from a different directory.  Consider this problem solved.

Comment: Are you changing the directory using Environment.CurrentDirectory?  Or setting the working directory in a shortcut?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running from a different directory?" Does your application do something that could require special permissions, such as accessing the file system?

Comment: I'm simply running from the command line.  Let's say the tool is located at C:\temp\debug.  But, I'm in directory c:\temp and attempting to run "C:\temp\debug\tool.exe".  I have been able to use a shortcut successfully because it includes a working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re: why the property is null

I suspect that InitializeComponent is trying to load some resources and is looking in the WorkingDirectory for the resources file.

Try this:

```
var realWD = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Environment.CurrentDirectory =
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
InitializeComponent();
Environment.CurrentDirectory = realWD;
```

**Edit:** just reformatted to avoid horizontal scrolling.

-Jesse

Comment: That in fact what was going on.  Not sure why an exception wasn't being blown when I was attempting to de-serialize a non-existent file.

Comment: Some exceptions are caught internally by InitializeComponent, or a deeper piece of code.